# Using an index to find a position in a matrix

Tags: javascript

My title might be terrible, but I can explain exactly what I want here. First of all, I am challenging myself to something very specific. Even if you guess what I'm trying to accomplish, please keep your answers on topic to what I am asking here, and not the overall problem I am solving.

I have a string of 25 generated letters.
I get an index of a letter via `str.indexOf(c)` and let's say that index is 16.
Visualize that `str` is a linear representation of a 5x5 table, thus an index of 16 would be the 4th row, 2nd column of that table.

I'm trying to find a way to find the row and column using javascript without looping through like this:

```
var row = 1;
var index = str.indexOf(c) + 1;
while(index > 5) {
    index = index - 5;
    row++;
}
```

With the above code, if index starts as 16, my end result will be row 4, index 2 - which is what I want. It just feels like there should be a way to do this with an algorithm instead of a loop.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As per the comments below, I'm feeling a tad silly. When I tried simple division, I kept getting a result of 3.2, which was not what I wanted. It didn't occur to me to simply add 1 (as I want a row number, not an index). Thank you all for the quick answers, and I'm sorry that my question was so brainless that it deserved a few down votes. I have to try harder to build a better reputation so I can up vote helpful answers in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use maths?

```
var index = 16;
var columnsPerRow = 5;
row = parseInt(index / columnsPerRow) + 1;
column = index % columnsPerRow + 1;
```

Comment: index / columnsPerRow   16/5 = 3.2

Comment: I'm accepting this one as you were first, but I found you don't need to add one to the modulus. My brain is a bit dead from work, I kept doing index/col and getting 3.2, which didn't equal the 4.2 I was expecting. I didn't think to add one...

Comment: @JonathanWalker: It all depends on if you start counting rows and columns from 0 or 1. And if you start counting one one way, in the interest of consistency, it seems like a good idea to me to do it with the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are replicating division and modulus in this code sample, you can achieve the same thing by doing `row = Math.floor(index / 5)` and `col = index % 5`.

```js
var index = parseInt(prompt('Numeric Index'));
var row = Math.floor(index / 5) + 1;
var col = index % 5;

alert('[ ' + col + ', ' + row + ' ]');
```

Comment: Wouldn't Math.ceil give you the wrong row if there's no remainder?

Comment: It would be Math.floor(), you need to trim the decimal off

Comment: Also, you need to add 1 to get the row number, not its index. :)

Comment: Thank you, this one was helpful as well, but without adding 1 to the row, the position was off. I'm feeling a tad silly that I didn't consider division and modulus - but it's been a long, long day and I think i was looking for a harder answer. I cannot up vote yet, so I hope others do instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop, you can just create a function

```
function findPosition(index, cols) {
  var rowIndex = parseInt(index/cols) + 1;
  var colIndex = index % cols;

  return {rowIndex: rowIndex, colIndex: colIndex}
}
```

So in your case string index is 17, and your matrix col is 5
you will be calling findPosition(17, 5) and it will return {rowIndex: 4, colIndex: 2}

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can just use the remainder (or modulus) to find the column and the whole number to find the row.

```
function getPosition(str, character, gridWidth) {
  var index = str.indexOf(character);
  var row = Math.floor(index/gridWidth);
  var col = index%gridWidth;
  return {row:row, col:col};
}
```

Then use it like this

```
var str = "hello sir";
console.log(getPosition(str, "i", 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can caluclate the position, this solution depend on Matrix start at 0, 0 not 1, 1 add 1 to row and column if you want to start from index 1:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
number = 16
per_row = 5
index = array.indexOf(number)
row = Math.floor(index/ per_row )
column = index % per_row
```